# How do I make the Lazarus IDE look and work like Delphi 2007 or newer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, pascal, lazarus

I've begun working with using Lazarus to make some simple utilities for my own use on Ubuntu 9.10. I know many people like the modular Delphi 7 layout, but I prefer a docked layout.

I'd also like to have the Delphi 2007 palette menu. Is this possible within the latest version of Lazarus (v0.9.28.x) ?

How can I configure Lazarus to look like, or behave like, Delphi 2007/9/10?

NOTE: This question is very old. It's now (2023) possible to configure Lazarus to appear *more* Delphi-like, and has been for a few years. [Here's a good guide](https://github.com/FlKo/LazarusDockedDesktops).

Kudos and thanks to the Lazarus developers for their amazing work!

Comment: I did find this add-on component which combines the Messages window with the source editor: http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Manual_Docker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Anchor Docking. It Helps, but, not change the menu.

From the Lazarus main menu pick "Package" - "Install/Uninstall Packages" and install the "anchordockingdsgn" package

https://wiki.freepascal.org/Anchor_Docking

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure that you can make it look like the newer Delphi IDEs.

I've used it in the past and I think that the D7 look is the only available option.

You could always edit the source and change it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no option to have the palette menu like Delphi 2007 in Lazarus. I think there is also a reason for this: the Lazarus developers are mostly 'hard core, oldschool' Delphi programmers, and this kind of programmers seems to prefer the Delphi 7 tools menu.

Comment: While partially true, I think the bigger problem is that it also isn't exactly non-trivial to implement such a thing crossplatform.

Answer (score 0):

It's open source, you can code it...

Comment: or test it. Start with the drag and drop stuff Dodi is working on.

Comment: or ask for your money back. :-)